# Wordpress -> Fatal error: Cannot redeclare get_post_gallery() (previously declared in

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I just acquired a new wordpress theme (RockWell)
I uploaded it to the folder : Wp-content/themes but when i try to activate it i get this error :

```
Fatal error: Cannot redeclare get_post_gallery() (previously declared in C:\D\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-includes\media.php:3314) in C:\D\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\rock\functions.php on line 243
```

I would be grateful if somebody could help with this issue or give me some advice.

Thank you in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using an outdated version of Rockwell theme. You need to update your theme which will fix this issue.

Comment: do you know the wordpress version that is compatible with rockwell 1.7.1?

Comment: I would not suggest you to use an older WordPress version. If you don't want to upgrade your theme right away, then I would suggest you rename the function get_post_gallery() to something else in functions.php and where ever else it appears.

Answer (score 1):

Your theme has a function called get_post_gallery() which has already been declared in functions.php but was set in the new theme too.

You would be best to check to ensure the theme is compatible with the version of Wordpress that you're using.

Failing that you could take a look at the source code and rename the offending method.